# why the animation screen is not rendering in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering

This is my react code. While data is null. it should render the loading animation. but for some reason it's not working. actually untill data is available the entire component is not being rendered. what should I do?

**The Card Component**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
export default function Card(props) { 
    let data = props.data  
    let [title, setTitle] = useState('') 
    let [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState('')  
    let [releaseYear, setReleaseYear] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
            if (data) {
                if (data.originalTitleText && data.originalTitleText.text) {
                    setTitle(data.originalTitleText.text);
                } else {
                    setTitle('');
                }
    
                if (data.primaryImage && data.primaryImage.url) {
                    setImageUrl(data.primaryImage.url);
                } else {
                    setImageUrl('');
                } 
                if (data.releaseYear && data.releaseYear.year) { 
                    setReleaseYear(data.releaseYear.year);  
                } else { 
                    setReleaseYear('');
                    }
            }
        }, [data]); 
        console.log(data)

    return ( 
       
          <div className=' w-72 h-64 shadow-xl  mx-4 flex-shrink-0 rounded-lg flex flex-col justify-between  pb-4'> 
              
              { data? 
                  <>
                  <img className="rounded-t-lg w-full aspect-[1498/836]" src={imageUrl} alt="" /> 
                  <p className='text-center'>{releaseYear}</p>
                  <p className='text-center'>{title}</p> 
                  </> 
                  : <div className='h-full w-full grid place-content-center'>
                        <div className='h-10 w-10 rounded-full loading animate-spin'></div>
                    </div> 
              }  
               </div>
       
    )
}
```

**The UpcomingMovies component**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Card from './Card'
import axios from 'axios';

export default  function UpcomingMovies() {
    let [data, setData] = useState(null);
   
    async function fetchData() { 
      const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com/titles/x/upcoming',
        params: {
          limit: '20'
        },
        headers: {
          'X-RapidAPI-Key': 'a006e3ad63msh0395ff02df10149p16eb19jsn416bc54d8f67',
          'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'moviesdatabase.p.rapidapi.com'
        }
      };
      // handle any error
      try {
        const response = await axios.request(options); 
        setData(response.data)
        console.log(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    } 
    // run once when the component loads
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchData() 
      console.log(data)
    },[]); 

    const cardData = data?.results
    .filter((item) => item.primaryImage?.url) // Filter out items without image URL
    .map((item, index) => <Card key={index} data={item} />);

    
    return ( 
      <> 
        <div className='bg-black text-white h-10 w-full'>Upcoming Movies</div>
        <div className='p-4 pt-2 flex flex-nowrap overflow-x-scroll '> 
          
          {cardData}
        </div> 
      </>
    )
  }
```

**index.css**

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';



@layer components {
    .loading {
      background: radial-gradient(closest-side, white 79%, transparent 81% 100%),
                  conic-gradient(#00be10 75%, #6aff7e 0);
    }                  
}
```

[image]

Screen should look like this for a while. untill data is not null.
[image]